# How to not lose a data from the list when going from one screen to another screen in flutter?

Tags: list, flutter, state-management

I have a class `ViewTotalItemProvider` which extends the ChangeNotifier. Inside the class, there is a list like this.

```
class ViewTotalItemProvider extends ChangeNotifier{
List<CartPlantLists> cartPlantList3 = [];
}
```

Additionally, there are 3 screens including class like, `PlantFeatureScreen1`, `ParticularPlant2`, `CartDetais3`. All are stateful widget and I am adding some items in second screen i.e. `ParticularPlant2` class. 

When I try to show the items from list in the second screen and the third screen it works.

But the value is not updated in the firstScreen i.e. `PlantFeatureScreen1`. However, when I reload the app, it shows the updated value. 
why is this happening? How can I solve it?

**Code**
ViewTotalItemProvider

```
List<CartPlantLists> cartPlantList3 = [];

class ViewTotalItemProvider extends ChangeNotifier{

  addQuantity(index){
     cartPlantList3[index].qu++;
    notifyListeners();
  }

  subtrachQuantity(index){
    cartPlantList3[index].qu--;
    notifyListeners();

  }
}
```

firstScreen `PlantFeatureScreen1` (Here I want to update the value in the very last widget)

```
class PlantFeatureScreen1 extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _PlantFeatureScreen1State createState() => _PlantFeatureScreen1State();
}

class _PlantFeatureScreen1State extends State<PlantFeatureScreen1> {


  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return ChangeNotifierProvider<ViewTotalItemProvider>(
      create: (context) => ViewTotalItemProvider(),
      child:Builder(builder: (context) {
        return           Column(
        children: <Widget>[
          TopAppBar(),
          Expanded(
            flex: 1,
            child: Align(
              alignment: Alignment(-1, 0),
              child: Container(
                decoration: BoxDecoration(
                  color: Colors.white,
                ),
                child: Text(
                  "Plants",
                  style: TextStyle(fontSize: 30, fontWeight: FontWeight.w700),
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ),
          Expanded(
            flex: 5,
            child: Container(
              width: double.infinity,
              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                color: Colors.blue,
              ),
              child: DefaultTabController(
                length: 5,
                child: Column(
                  children: [
                    Container(
                      height: 50,
                      width: double.infinity,
                      child: TabBar(
                        isScrollable: true,
                        tabs: ourAllLists.tabMaker(),
                      ),
                    ),
                    Container(
                      height: 317,
                      width: double.infinity,
                      decoration: BoxDecoration(color: Colors.white),
                      child: TabBarView(
                        children: ourAllLists.tabViewerMaker(context),),),
                  ],
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ),
          Padding(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(20, 0, 20, 20),
            child: Container(
              alignment: Alignment.bottomRight,
              height: 120,
              width: double.infinity,
              child: Stack(
                overflow: Overflow.visible,
                children: [
                  Container(
                    height: 70,
                    width: 105,
                    decoration: BoxDecoration(
                        color: Color(0xFF96CA2D),
                        borderRadius: BorderRadiusDirectional.horizontal(
                            end: Radius.circular(32),
                            start: Radius.circular(32))),
                            child: Icon(FontAwesomeIcons.shoppingBag,color:Colors.white,size:30),
                  ),
                  Positioned(
                    // top: 0,
                    bottom: 50,
                    right: 0,
                    child: Consumer<ViewTotalItemProvider>(
                      builder: (context, value, child){
                        return Container(
                        height: 35,
                        width: 35,
                        decoration: BoxDecoration(
                          color: Colors.white,
                          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(50),
                          border: Border.all(color: Color(0xFF96CA2D),width: 4)
                        ),
                        child: Center(child: Text(ourAllLists.totalquantity().toString(),style:TextStyle(fontSize: 20,color: Color(0xFF96CA2D)))),
                      );
                      }),                
                    ),
                ],
              ),
            ),
          )
        ],
      );   
      })
 );
  }
}
```

secondScreen `ParticularPlant2`

```
class ParticularPlant2 extends StatefulWidget {
  final indexNumber;
  ParticularPlant2({@required this.indexNumber});

  @override
  _ParticularPlant2State createState() => _ParticularPlant2State();
}

class _ParticularPlant2State extends State<ParticularPlant2> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: SafeArea(
        child: Scaffold(
          body: Column(
            crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
            children: [
              TopAppBar(),
              Container(
                decoration: BoxDecoration(
                  color: Colors.red,
                  borderRadius: BorderRadiusDirectional.only(
                    bottomStart: Radius.circular(50),
                  ),
                ),
                child: Column(
                  crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                  children: [
                    Text(
                      ourAllLists
                          .mainListAllPlantDetailsList1[widget.indexNumber].pN,
                      style: kPlantNameStyle,
                    ),
                    Text(
                      ourAllLists
                          .mainListAllPlantDetailsList1[widget.indexNumber].ca
                          .toUpperCase(),
                      style: TextStyle(
                        fontSize: 15,
                      ),
                    ),
                    Text(
                      "\$" +
                          ourAllLists
                              .mainListAllPlantDetailsList1[widget.indexNumber]
                              .pr
                              .toString(),
                      style: kItemPrice,
                    ),
                    SizedBox(height: 100),
                    Row(
                      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceAround,
                      children: [
                        Column(
                          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
                          children: [
                            Container(
                              height: 80,
                              width: 80,
                              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                  color: Colors.white,
                                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(50)),
                              child: Icon(
                                FontAwesomeIcons.flag,
                                color: Color(0xFF9DCD3C),
                              ),
                            ),
                            SizedBox(
                              height: 50,
                            ),
                            FlatButton(
                              onPressed: () {
                                final tile = cartPlantList3.firstWhere(
                                    (item) =>
                                        item.pN ==
                                        ourAllLists
                                            .mainListAllPlantDetailsList1[
                                                widget.indexNumber]
                                            .pN,
                                    orElse: () => null);
                                if (tile != null) {
                                } else {
                                  cartPlantList3.add(
                                    CartPlantLists(
                                      quantity: 1,
                                      plantName: ourAllLists
                                          .mainListAllPlantDetailsList1[
                                              widget.indexNumber]
                                          .pN,
                                      category: ourAllLists
                                          .mainListAllPlantDetailsList1[
                                              widget.indexNumber]
                                          .ca,
                                      price: ourAllLists
                                          .mainListAllPlantDetailsList1[
                                              widget.indexNumber]
                                          .pr,
                                    ),
                                  );
                                }
                                print(cartPlantList3.length);
                              },
                              child: Container(
                                height: 80,
                                width: 80,
                                decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                    color: Color(0xFF9DCD3C),
                                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(50)),
                                child: Icon(FontAwesomeIcons.shoppingBag,
                                    color: Colors.white),
                              ),
                            )
                          ],
                        ),
                        Container(
                          height: 250,
                          child: Image(image: AssetImage("assets/tulip.png")),
                        )
                      ],
                    )
                  ],
                ),
              )
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: please provide your code on how you access the items in both the second screen and the third screen

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems like you are using Provider the wrong way. The best way to do this in your scenario is to wrap MaterialApp inside MyApp() in your main.dart file with MultiProvider. Try something like this: https://pub.dev/packages/provider#multiprovider You can place a ChangeNotifierProvider inside it.

```
return MultiProvider(
  providers: [
    ChangeNotifierProvider<ViewTotalItemProvider>(
        create: (context) => ViewTotalItemProvider()),
  ],
  child: MaterialApp(...)
);
```

Also, you have to place a getter and setter in your Model. Here is an example:

```
class ImageModel extends ChangeNotifier {
  String _base64Image;
  get base64Image => _base64Image;
  set base64Image(String base64Image) {
    _base64Image = base64Image;
    notifyListeners();
  }
}
```

I would also recommend using Selector instead of Consumer (Ideally, you should use Selector instead of Consumer so that the widget only rebuilds if the value its listening to changes) Here is an example based on the model above:

```
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
 //other widgets
 Selector<ImageModel, String>(
  selector: (_, model) => model.base64Image,
  builder: (_, image, __) {
   return Text(image);
     },
   );
  }
 )
}
```

Here is how you can get and set it using a RaisedButton:

```
class _PlantFeatureScreen1State extends State<PlantFeatureScreen1> {
  final itemModel;
  List<CartPlantLists> myList=[];
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    itemModel = Provider.of<ViewTotalItemProvider>(context,listen:false);
    print(itemModel.yourVariable); //getting the value
    return Container(
             child: RaisedButton(
               child:Text("Set Item");
               onPressed:(){
               itemModel.yourVariable=myList; //setting the value
               },
             ),
    );
  }
 }
```

Hope this helps! Good Luck!

Comment: I still have to reload my app to see the updated value.

Comment: not sure why its not working but I have two alternate solutions in mind. One is a hacky solution which call setState after your second screen is popped and the other one is to use Bloc to update the value. @AmanChaudhary tell me which solution you would like. I'll make an answer.

Comment: By the way, please see the `ViewTotalItemProvider` class. Over there I have put list outside the class. Do I have to put this inside the class and make getter of it?

Comment: Yes, you need to place a getter for it. Place the getter inside your class. Try checking if it works.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/219938/discussion-between-aman-chaudhary-and-uni).

Comment: Please help me with the concept of getter and setter and the provider package. I am stuck on this. It would be awesome if we could discuss in chat about this

Answer (score 2):

Step 1:
add the dependency for the provider pattern in the **pubspec.yaml** file

```
dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter
  provider: ^4.1.2
```

Step 2:
create provider in seperate file :

```
class ViewTotalItemProvider with ChangeNotifier{
List<CartPlantLists> _cartPlantList1 = [];
get cartPlantList1 => _cartPlantList1 ;

  set cartPlantList1 (List<CartPlantLists> selected){
   _cartPlantList1 = selected;
     notifyListeners();
  }
}
```

step 3:
Use MultiProvider to wrap the MaterialApp widget in **main.dart**.

```
void main() => runApp(
   MultiProvider (providers: [
      ChangeNotifierProvider<ViewTotalItemProvider>.value(value: 
          ViewTotalItemProvider()),
                          ], 
                child: MyApp()
                )
            );
class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
        home: HomePage(),  
    );
  }
}
```

Step 4:
use provider in your screen PlantFeatureScreen1 :

```
class PlantFeatureScreen1 extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _PlantFeatureScreen1State createState() => _PlantFeatureScreen1State();
}

class _PlantFeatureScreen1State extends State<PlantFeatureScreen1> {
  var viewTotalItemProvider;
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    viewTotalItemProvider = Provider.of<ViewTotalItemProvider>(context);
    return Scaffold(
      .......
    );
  }
  }
```

step 5:
get cartPlantList1.

```
     List<CartPlantLists> list = viewTotalItemProvider.cartPlantList1;
```

step 6 : set cartPlantList1.

```
    List<CartPlantLists> list = [];
    ...
    viewTotalItemProvider.cartPlantList1 = list;
```

similarly u can use for other two classes.

Comment: I am new to flutter and I am trying to learn how to use the provider package.
 I did up to step 4 and everything looks good.
Please assist me with steps 5 and 6. I am confused about where to get and set it. And what is the reason behind doing that?

Comment: @AmanChaudhary look at my answer above. You can set it inside onTap() or onPressed() or in any function.

Comment: I did the same, but firstScreen does not update the value automatically. I again have to reload the app

Comment: @AmanChaudhary check my answer out. It didn't update it that quick

Comment: u have to declare ````viewTotalItemProvider = Provider.of<ViewTotalItemProvider>(context);````  as in step 4 for every screen u want to use or update.