# Add the widgets to the list dynamically and conditionally flutter

Tags: flutter

I am trying to add the widgets of the items that are selected from list of checkbox. I am getting the list of items checked but unable to add the widgets conditionally. I have implemented as follows:

Checkbox list items

```
responseData = [
  MachinesData(0, "गाई", false),
  MachinesData(1, "भैंसी    ", false),
  MachinesData(2, " चौरी/याक    ", false),
  MachinesData(3, "गोरु/राँगा   ", false),
  MachinesData(4, "भेँडा/बाख्रा/च्याङ्ग्रा ", false),
  MachinesData(5, "बङ्गुर/ सुङ्गुर/ बँदेल", false),
  MachinesData(6, "कुखुरा ", false),
  MachinesData(7, "अन्य पन्छीहरु  ", false),
  MachinesData(8, "मत्स्य  ", false),
  MachinesData(9, "घाँसबाली   ", false),
  MachinesData(10, "अन्य (पशुपन्छी तथा मत्स्य)    ", false),
];
```

When these list of items from dialog are selected I am getting the list of index, names and checkedValues in main class as follows:

```
onChecked(var value, int i, String name) {
setState(() {
  if (responseData[i].isChecked == true) {
    checkIndex.add(i);
    nonRepated.add(responseData[i].name);             
  } else {
    nonRepated.remove(responseData[i].name);       
  }
});  
}
```

Now I need to check the name the items and add their respective widgets or any other better methods to check condition are appreciated. They may be one or more selected items with different layouts also I need to remove respect layout if user presses an icon. Could not move forward from these above steps.

Comment: This could be solved using state management: https://flutter.dev/docs/development/data-and-backend/state-mgmt/options Take a look at this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/63444439/9522732 You can achieve the same thing but you would have to change ```_base64Image``` in ImageModel to a List<MachinesData> myData and add a function where you can add your data. void addListData(MachinesData data){ myData.add(data);} then you could call it with itemModel.addListData(myDataIwanttoadd) (look where itemModel is in my answer)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I added the identifier to the responseData as:

```
 responseData = [
  PData(0, "गाई", 'cow', false),
  PData(1, "भैंसी   ", 'buffalo', false),
  PData(2, " चौरी/याक   ", 'yak', false),
  PData(3, "गोरु/राँगा  ", 'ox', false),
  PData(4, "भेँडा/बाख्रा/च्याङ्ग्रा ", 'sheep', false),
  PData(5, "बङ्गुर/ सुङ्गुर/ बँदेल", 'pig', false),
  PData(6, "कुखुरा ", 'chicken', false),
  PData(7, "अन्य पन्छीहरु  ", 'birds', false),
  PData(8, "मत्स्य  ", 'fish', false),
  PData(9, "घाँसबाली   ", 'grass', false),
  PData(10, "अन्य (पशुपन्छी तथा मत्स्य)    ", 'other', false),
];
```

Callback function:

```
 onChecked(var value, int i, String name) {
    setState(() {
      if (responseData[i].isChecked == true) {
      
  identifiers.add(responseData[i].identifier);
        nonRepated.add(responseData[i].name);             
      } else {
 identifiers.remove(responseData[i].identifier);
        nonRepated.remove(responseData[i].name);       
      }
    });  
    }
```

Build Method:

```
 for (int i = 0; i < identifiers.length; i++)
        _MachineData(identifiers, i, nonRepated[i], checkIndex[i]),
```

MachineData widget

```
 Widget _MachineData(var params, int i, String nonRepate, int checkInde) {
switch (params[i]) {
  case 'cow':
    return Cow(nonRepated, i, checkInde, nonRepate, onDelete);
  case 'buffalo':
    return Buffalo(nonRepated, i, checkInde, nonRepate, onDelete);
  
  default:
    return Container();
}
}
```