# Flutter - How can I reuse some code at multiple places

Tags: flutter, dart, mobile, flutter-layout, flutter-dependencies

Hi I have a app where I will be making a book and this book will be with images,

I am trying to reuse code meaning how to add code within a method and than have that method at different areas but only change the image in each method .. .to make the code more reusable??? the code will stay the same but the image in each code block will change... i dont want to copy and paste the code again and again.

```
    import 'dart:ui';
    import 'package:adobe_xd/adobe_xd.dart';
    import 'dart:io';
    import 'package:Quran_highlighter/main.dart';
    import 'package:flutter/rendering.dart';
    import 'package:system_shortcuts/system_shortcuts.dart';
    import 'package:Quran_highlighter/Widgets/NavDrawer.dart';
    import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
    import 'package:zoom_widget/zoom_widget.dart';
    import 'package:flutter/gestures.dart';
    import 'package:Quran_highlighter/Widgets/size_config.dart';
    import 'package:flutter_slidable/flutter_slidable.dart';
    
    class Aliflaammeem extends StatefulWidget {
      @override
      _AliflaammeemState createState() => _AliflaammeemState();
    }
    
    class _AliflaammeemState extends State<Aliflaammeem> {
    
      @override
      Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        var screenSizes = MediaQuery.of(context).size;
        return Scaffold(
            appBar: new AppBar(title: new Text("1 Alif-laam-meem آلم, Pg2")),
            // return DefaultTextStyle(
            // style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.bodyText2,
            body: LayoutBuilder(builder:
                (BuildContext context, BoxConstraints viewportConstraints) {
              return SingleChildScrollView(
                  child: Stack(children: <Widget>[
                new Slidable(
                  delegate: new SlidableDrawerDelegate(),
                  actionExtentRatio: 0.10,
                  // body: Center,
                  child: SafeArea(
                    top: true,
                    bottom: true,
                    right: true,
                    left: true,
                    child: new Container(
                      **child: new Image.asset(
                        "test/assets/Para 1 - Alif-laam-meem no color/quranpg2.png",**
                        fit: BoxFit.cover,
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                  actions: <Widget>[
                    new IconSlideAction(
                        caption: 'English',
                        // color: Colors.lightBlue,
                        color: Colors.blueGrey,
                        icon: Icons.language,
                        foregroundColor: Colors.lightBlue,
                        // color: Colors.black,
                        // ),
                        onTap: () {
                          Navigator.push(
                            context,
                            MaterialPageRoute(
                                builder: (context) => Changepg2topg3()),
                          );
                        }),
                    new IconSlideAction(
                        caption: 'Forward',
                        // color: Colors.greenAccent,
                        // color: Colors.black87,
                        icon: Icons.arrow_back_ios,
                        foregroundColor: Colors.greenAccent,
                        onTap: () {
                          Navigator.push(
                            context,
                            MaterialPageRoute(
                                builder: (context) => Changepg2topg3()),
                          );
                        }),
                    // ),
                  ],
                  secondaryActions: <Widget>[
                    new IconSlideAction(
                      caption: 'Back',
                      // color: Colors.red[200],
                      icon: Icons.arrow_forward_ios,
                      foregroundColor: Colors.red[200],
                      // color: Colors.black87,
    
                      // onTap: () => _showSnackBar('More'),
                    ),
                    new IconSlideAction(
                      caption: 'Arabic',
                      // color: Colors.yellow[800],
                      icon: Icons.brightness_4,
                      foregroundColor: Colors.yellow[800],
                      color: Colors.blueGrey,
    
                      // onTap: () =>
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
              ]));
            }));
      }
    }
   //I WANT THE TOP CODE TO BE THE GLOBAL CODE WHICH WILL REUSED AGAIN AND 

AGAIN IN THE SAME CLASS - AND IF I CHANGE SOMETHING UP THERE, I WANT IT TO AUTOMATICALLY CHANGE THROUGHOUT ALL THE PAGES 
    AND BELOW WE HAVE THE SAME CODE WHICH I COPIED AND PASTED - AND JUST CHANGED THE IMAGE AND APPBAR TITLE....  I NEED TO SEE HOW I CAN ACHIEVE THIS WITHOUT COPY AND PASTING....



    class Changepg2topg3 extends StatelessWidget {
      @override
      Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        var screenSizes = MediaQuery.of(context).size;
        return Scaffold(
            appBar: new AppBar(title: new Text("1 Alif-laam-meem آلم, Pg3")),
            // return DefaultTextStyle(
            // style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.bodyText2,
            body: LayoutBuilder(builder:
                (BuildContext context, BoxConstraints viewportConstraints) {
              return SingleChildScrollView(
                  child: Stack(children: <Widget>[
                new Slidable(
                  delegate: new SlidableDrawerDelegate(),
                  actionExtentRatio: 0.10,
                  // body: Center,
                  child: SafeArea(
                    top: true,
                    bottom: true,
                    right: true,
                    left: true,
                    child: new Container(
                      // padding: EdgeInsets.zero,
                      **child: new Image.asset(
                        `"test/assets/Para 1 - Alif-laam-meem no color/quranpg3.png",*`*
                        // fit: BoxFit.fitidth,
                        fit: BoxFit.cover,
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                  actions: <Widget>[
                    new IconSlideAction(
                      caption: 'English',
                      color: Colors.lightBlue,
                      icon: Icons.language,
    
                      // onTap: () =>
                    ),
                    new IconSlideAction(
                      caption: 'Forward',
    
                      color: Colors.greenAccent,
                      icon: Icons.arrow_back_ios,
                      // onTap: () => _showSnackBar('Share'),
                    ),
                  ],
                  secondaryActions: <Widget>[
                    new IconSlideAction(
                        caption: 'Back',
                        color: Colors.red[200],
                        icon: Icons.arrow_forward_ios,
                        onTap: () {
                          Navigator.push(
                            context,
                            MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => Aliflaammeem()),
                          );
                        }),
                    // ),
                    new IconSlideAction(
                      caption: 'Arabic',
                      color: Colors.yellow[800],
                      icon: Icons.brightness_4,
                      // onTap: () =>
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
              ]));
              // );
            }));
      }
    }
    
    // }
```

Comment: You'd want to learn state managment: https://flutter.dev/docs/development/data-and-backend/state-mgmt/options . I recommend starting out with Provider then switch to Bloc. I explained how to use Provider here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63444318/how-to-not-lose-a-data-from-the-list-when-going-from-one-screen-to-another-scree/63444439#63444439

Comment: I am trying to reuse code meaning how to add code within a method and than have that method at different areas but only change the image in each method .. .to make the code more reusable

Comment: thats not a good way of "reusing" the code. Take a look at state management first and compare which solution is better at reusing the code.

Comment: So i tried reading through your example but not sure if thats what i am looking for... i want to write the code once - as a global variable and reuse it again and again but only change  the image, there will be 846 images and i want to ensure the code and all the buttons all will remain consistent page to page.   can you show me an example relevant to my example please... ? i have changed the above to only reflect the code i want to reuse

Comment: I don't really have an example for that but I think you'd have to use Provider and Bloc. It's not good to just pass around data from widget to widget.

Answer (score 0):

1.Make a class returning a list
2.Make a New Widget function and pass-in the list to this function

Comment: I am extremely new to flutter, can you please elaborate